# Хочу написать библиотеку с отправкой на GitHub под Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

Как лучше организовать проект в файловой системе? Делать и библиотеку и тест в одном проекте и исключать тест с помощью gitignore, или же лучше разделить на 2 проекта: библиотека и тест? Библиотеки раньше не писал, поэтому теряюсь.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Тесты следует включать в исходники библиотеки и помещать на GitHub (то есть не включать в .gitignore). При сборке тесты просто должны исключаться из результирующей jar. Вообще есть стандартные структуры проектов для библиотек (обычных java проектов, без web-части) — Maven или Gradle. Для библиотеки лучше всего сборка на Gradle подойдет, потому что ее можно гибче настроить, например, для тех же тестов.

Проект на GitHub можно интегрировать с [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/). Он будет в фоне собирать проект и проверять сборку вашими же тестами. Это одна из причин почему тесты должны быть включены в исходники проекта.